# How to mock service method?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing

I have a strange problem. When I test the "edit" method I receive an exception. I know how to fix it: I have to add null checking of "it" in the "let" block in the "edit" method - but this situation shouldn't ever have a place. Let me know what you think about it. What should I change?

Controller:

```
@PatchMapping("{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
fun edit(@PathVariable id: Long, @Valid @RequestBody baseData: EditOrganizationRequest?) =
        manageOrganizationService.update(id, baseData!!).let {
            EntityModel.of(it)
        }
```

Service:

```
override fun update(id: Long, baseData: EditOrganizationRequest): OrganizationEntity {
    return findOrganization(id).apply {
        name = baseData.name
        organizationRepository.save(this)
    }
}

private fun findOrganization(id: Long) = organizationRepository.findByIdOrNull(id)
        ?: throw ResourceNotFoundException()
```

Test:

```
@Test
fun `#edit should return "not found" error`() {
    val baseData = EditOrganizationRequest("New name")
    given(manageOrganizationService.fetchOne(1))
            .willThrow(ResourceNotFoundException::class.java)

    mvc.patch("/organizations/1") {
        contentType = APPLICATION_JSON
        content = asJsonString(baseData)
    }.andExpect {
        status { isBadRequest() }
        content { contentType(HAL_JSON_VALUE) }
    }
}
```

Test result:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Content must not be null!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. I mocked another method then I used.